# SELF-TEST Failed

Tags: hard-drive, disk

I recently (approx 6m) bought a refurbished laptop online, which had two hard disks installed. I installed Ubuntu on one of them and run the laptop as a dual-boot Windows/Linux machine - this has been working without significant issues. However, recently I encountered regular issues with the machine, where Ubuntu wanted to send operation system error messages to HQ, and a few applications just suddenly refused to load.
I don't think it is a virus as I ran clamTK with no discoveries of infection. Hence I followed up with potential hardware issues and I encountered the below while trouble-shooting.

I don't quite understand the report -- is this hard drive in terminal decline, or are these tests failing simply because this is the Windows partition (and my laptop issue doesn't lie with the hard disk)?

I am an amateur Linux-user, this is my first machine running Linux.

[image: Disks error report]

Comment: The SMART tests test the drive, not partitions on it.  If the SMART tests start failing, it is likely that drive failure is imminent.  Backup anything you care about on that drive immediately.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue on my HP laptop, and i did a backup in case that i lose my data, but after a week tried testing short self-test again and i got "Disk is OK" instead.

[Disk screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTqSW.png)

So just backup your all your data and you're fine... the disk is not likely gonna fail.

Comment: So it seems ubuntu was able to isolate the bad sectors and change the status of the disk to OK. Have you done that manually? I mean checking for bad sectors?